# Unrecognized field "User" (Class com.test.webservice.bean.User), not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jackson-modules

Hello I am trying to convert the below json object through the jersey service,

```
{
    "User": {
        "username": "newusername",
        "password": "newpassword",
        "email": "test.test@test.com",
        "address": "test",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "city": "test"
    }
}
```

I get below mentioned error :

```
Unrecognized field "User" (Class com.test.webservice.bean.User), not marked as ignorable

 at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@1dad89c0; line: 11, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.test.webservice.bean.User["User"])
```

Also if I set @JsonIgnoreProperties to TRUE, the complete user object is ignored and i receive NULL values for all fields.

I am also aware about ObjectMapper which I have set as below :

```
private static ObjectMapper createCustomObjectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .setAnnotationIntrospector(createJaxbJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
    }
```

I am using jackson 2.0,following is the sample code of User bean

```
**package com.test.webservice.bean;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @JsonCreator
    public User(
            @JsonProperty("username") String username,
            @JsonProperty("password") String password,
            @JsonProperty("email") String email,
            @JsonProperty("firstName") String FirstName,
            @JsonProperty("lastName") String LastName,
            @JsonProperty("address") String Address,
            @JsonProperty("city") String City) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.email = email;
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.LastName = LastName;
            this.Address = Address;
            this.City = City;
        }**
```

And if I set json object as below it Works fine

```
{
        "username": "newusername",
        "password": "newpassword",
        "email": "test.test@adrosonic.com",
        "address": "test",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "city": "test"
}
```

I want to know if this is how it is supposed to work or or if there is any workaround in this situation except changing the json string.

Thankyou for your time.